# User Report Builder With SSRS without opening 1433 port to DB

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I am looking for a solution to the following problem:

1. I have a web application that exposes a Data Warehouse using Views written in my MS-SQL DB
2. I let the clients of my application use Report Builder to create RDL files against these Views
3. My application then uploads the RDL files to the SSRS server and makes the required modifications to allow users displaying these reports in different places in my Application.

*The problem:*
As long as the client's machine has access to the MS SQL server using port 1433 i have no problems with the described scenario.

One of the clients has strict security polices and will not open port 1433 to the SQL server and because of that all the solution I have with reporting will not work.

Can you suggest a workaround or a different approach that will no have to use port 1433 ?

Event if it will require to install some additional software or expose the Views in a different way I'm looking for something that can help me create the same solution without the requirement of port 1433.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of is an RDP to another server or like a citrix published app or virtualized application where the host server it is running off of would have access